# Images are not displaying properly few images are displaying

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to display images from my local server XAMPP but the code is not working properly, only a few images are displaying. Can somebody solve this?

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    $query="select* from video order by 1 DESC Limit 0,10 ";

    $queryrun=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($queryrun)){
        $id=$result['id'];
        $title=substr($result['title'],0,21);
        $date=$result['date'];
        $artist=$result['artist'];
        $imglink=$result['imglink'];
        $vidlink=$result['vidlink'];
        $image=$result['image'];
?>           

<p>
    <center id="fsize">
        <ul id="newpost">
            <li>
                <a href="audio.php?watch=<?php echo $id; ?>/<?php echo $title; ?>">
                    <img src="images/<?php echo $image; ?>" height="40px" width="60px" />
                </a>
                <a href="audio.php?watch=<?php echo $id; ?>/<?php echo $title; ?>">
                    <?php echo $title; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </center>
</p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You seem to never use the variable called `$imgLink`

Comment: $imgLink is not in use

Comment: Have you tried debugging your array? Does `$image` always have a value at every iteration?

Comment: yes sir $image have its value

Comment: Given your code, what do you expect to see?

Comment: i want to display images with link

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="audio.php?watch=<?php echo $id.'/'.$title;?>">
        <img src="<?php echo 'images/'.$image;?>" height="40" width="60" />
    </a>
    <a href="audio.php?watch=<?php echo $id.'/'.$title;?>">
        <?php echo $title; ?>
    </a>
```

Try out this

Answer (score 0):

There could be problem with the path. If you are using relative path that is ok than. But if you are storing images path as an absolute path than it should be problem.echo the image path stored in database and check the path if its absolute convert it into relative path.

Comment: yes the path is absolute and i want to display images with link

Comment: Give it a try with relative path

Comment: thanks a lot sir , your idea works . Again thanks for your help .

Comment: Thats ok we are here to help out each other and to ask for help. Keep it up and upvote my answer. If you like.